# Onsen [ng:areq] Argument '' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, onsen-ui, monaca

I know that this question was asked about a hundred of times. And I tried many of the solutions. Sadly none worked for me.

I'm programming with Onsen and AngularJS.

HTML:

```
    <ons-template id="signin.html">
    <ons-dialog var="dialog">            
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Log In</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <div class="login-form" ng-app="SignIn" ng-controller="SignCtrl">
            <input type="email" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Email" value="">
            <input type="password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" value="">
            <br><br>
            <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button">Log In</ons-button>
            <br>
            <ons-button modifier="quiet" class="forgot-password">Forgot password?</ons-button>
            <ons-button modifier="quiet" class="forgot-password" ng-click="showSignUp()">Not a member?</ons-button>
        </div>

    </ons-dialog>
</ons-template>
```

Javascipt (js/signctrl.js):

```
(function(angular){
    // init functions
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('SignIn', []);
    app.controller('SignCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.showSignUp = function() {       
            alert("foo!");
            ons.createDialog('signup.html').then(function(dialog) { dialog.show(); });
        };
    });

})(window.angular);
```

And included files:

```
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/locations.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/monaca-onsenui/css/onsen-css-components-sunshine-theme.css">
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="js/signctrl.js"></script>
```

And ons.bootstrap() is called at the beginning (before including the js/signctrl.js).

I would be very happy if you can help me and appreciate your help.

PS: The full error is `[ng:areq] Argument 'SignCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

PPS: The real full error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SignCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=SignCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1460:4931
    at assertArg (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1460:18360)
    at assertArgFn (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1460:18562)
    at file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1462:20613
    at setupControllers (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1461:27741)
    at nodeLinkFn (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1461:28989)
    at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1461:21271)
    at file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1461:19821
    at pre (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1474:25379)
    at invokeLinkFn (file:///data/data/mobi.monaca.debugger/files/projects/cloud/570c898afd17349b6c3d57a4/www/components/loader.js:1462:13182)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Onsen, but do all the `ons-*` elements need to be inside the element containing `ng-app` and `ng-controller`?

Comment: They are predefined elements. They have to (in my case).
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: That's why I asked - because they aren't all inside the element containing `ng-app` and `ng-controller`.

Comment: Sorry, missunderstood you. They don't have to. I thought you ask me to try it with normal html elements.

Comment: The error you are getting means that `SignCtrl` was not registered as a controller before it was attempted to be used. Whether this is happening because there is another error further up the chain preventing that code from executing or because something is attempting to access `SignCtrl` before the bit of javascript that registers it has run is what you'll have to figure  out. Was there any other error at all in the console besides the `[ng:areq]` error?

Comment: Just checked it again. Sadly no. I also checked if all the code is executed by inserting alerts. Everything is executed except the $scope.showSignUp function. That's the reason why there is such a strange alert.

Error seems to be raised when the HTML is parsed by the loader.js (from Onsen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a timing issue. It's trying to access the controller before the element that contains the controller has been initialized.
To solve that, wrap your angular code on `ons.ready` function ([see the docs](https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#onsreadyfunction)), which will execute your code once onsen has been totally loaded.

For example:

```js
ons.ready(function() {

  //Your angular code

})
```

Also, it seems that you forgot to add onsen module to your controller.

Hope it solves your issue!